# Nearest Divisible Number with Iteration

Tags: javascript, iteration

I have this code
https://codepen.io/clickDcode/pen/jOOEQRQ

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ans;
  var num = document.getElementById("num").value;
  var div = document.getElementById("div").value;
  var mod = (Number(num) + Number(div)) % Number(div);

  if (mod == 0)
    var ans = num;
  else
    var ans = (Number(num) + Number(div)) - Number(mod);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ans;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Divisible by:
  <input type="number" id="div" name="text2" placeholder="0">
  <p/>
  <p>
    Your Number:
    <input type="number" id="num" name="text1" placeholder="0" onchange="myFunction()">
  </p>

  <p id="demo"></p>
```

Already finish about getting the nearest divisible number
Right now, I need to iterate (10) the answer like this
Example:

Divisible by: 22
Your Number: 55

(Ans: the nearest greater divisible is 66)

**The output must be:**

Divisible by: 22

Your Number: 55

66
88
110
132
154
176
198
220
242
264

(iterate the number by the divisible number use)

Comment: https://www.purplemath.com/modules/lcm_gcf.htm ?

Comment: Divisible number - I already finish it. my problem is the iteration which i mentioned in my post

Comment: PS: Do not use `var` more than once per variable: `ans = (mod == 0) ? num : (Number(num) + Number(div)) - Number(mod);`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ans = 0;
  var text = "";

  var num = document.getElementById("num").value;
  var div = document.getElementById("div").value;
  var mod = (Number(num) + Number(div)) % Number(div);

  if (mod == 0)
    var ans = num;
  else
    var ans = (Number(num) + Number(div)) - Number(mod);

  var init = 0;
  if (Number(ans) % Number(div) === 0) {
    text = addToText(text, ans)
    init = 1;
  }

  for (i = init; i < 10; i++) {
    ans = Number(ans) + Number(div);
    text = addToText(text, ans)
  }

  function addToText(text, ans) {
    return text + "Next TS : " + ans + "<br>";
  }

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;

}
```

```html
<p>
  Divisible by:
  <input type="number" id="div" name="text2" placeholder="0">
  <p/>
  <p>
    Your Number:
    <input type="number" id="num" name="text1" placeholder="0" onchange="myFunction()">
  </p>

  <p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about recursion?

```
function ndn(d, n, i, ac) {
    if (i === 0) return ac;
    var m = n % d;
    if (m !== 0) n += d - m;
    ac.push(n);
    return ndn(d, n + d, --i, ac);
}

ndn(22, 55, 10, []);
```